# ffmpeg '-i pipe:' and 'thread_queue_size' -- managing a pipe

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe, threads

I've discovered a thread_queue_size number that seems to work on my system for this use-case but I'll test more (or repeat tests) to help the cause if someone can suggest something. Please advise. Thanks,
Mark.

---

thread_queue_size 24883200  (to avoid "Thread message queue blocking")

The command line is VapourSynth (VSPIPE) piping raw frames plus FFMPEG deriving audio & subs from a concat of the VOBs, thus:

`VSPIPE --y4m C:\AVout\VTS_04_1(210820-023517.49).mkv.vpy - | FFMPEG -thread_queue_size 24883200 -i pipe: -i "concat:h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_1.VOB|h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_2.VOB|h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_3.VOB|h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_4.VOB|h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_5.VOB|h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_6.VOB" -filter_complex "[0:v]settb=expr=1/120,setpts=expr=N,setdar=16/9,setsar=32/27[v];[1:a:0]atempo=1.001[a0];[1:a:1]atempo=1.001[a1];[1:a:2]atempo=1.001[a2];[1:a:3]atempo=1.001[a3];[1:a:4]atempo=1.001[a4]" -map "[v]" -map "[a0]" -map "[a1]" -map "[a2]" -map "[a3]" -map "[a4]" -map 1:s -codec:v libx265 -x265-params "crf=18:qcomp=0.80:sao=no:strong-intra-smoothing=no" -codec:a:0 ac3 -codec:a:1 ac3 -codec:a:2 ac3 -codec:a:3 ac3 -codec:a:4 ac3 -codec:s copy -r 120 C:\AVout\VTS_04_1(210820-023517.49).mkv`

The result:

1, Transcoding proceeded at about speed=0.5.

2, While it ran, VSPIPE dominated the 8 threads (by a factor of ~2x over FFMPEG) and "System Commit" (sum of used RAM + used paging) maxed out at 126.3GB after rising steadily.

3, Console output of note was "Error: fwrite() call failed when writing frame: 331449, plane 2, errno: 22". It's hard to judge for sure, but it certainly appeared that the failure message printed at the same moment that "System Commit" topped out. On playback, video freezes at that precise point: frame 331449 (46:02.072) -- there should be 939036 frames (2:10:25.305).

---

thread_queue_size 2048

The command line is, again, VapourSynth (VSPIPE) piping raw frames et cetera (but this time with "-thread_queue_size 2048") thus:

`VSPIPE --y4m C:\AVout\VTS_04_1(210820-042617.65).mkv.vpy - | FFMPEG -thread_queue_size 2048 -i pipe: -i "concat:h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_1.VOB|h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_2.VOB|h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_3.VOB|h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_4.VOB|h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_5.VOB|h:\VIDEO_TS\VTS_04_6.VOB" -filter_complex "[0:v]settb=expr=1/120,setpts=expr=N,setdar=16/9,setsar=32/27[v];[1:a:0]atempo=1.001[a0];[1:a:1]atempo=1.001[a1];[1:a:2]atempo=1.001[a2];[1:a:3]atempo=1.001[a3];[1:a:4]atempo=1.001[a4]" -map "[v]" -map "[a0]" -map "[a1]" -map "[a2]" -map "[a3]" -map "[a4]" -map 1:s -codec:v libx265 -x265-params "crf=18:qcomp=0.80:sao=no:strong-intra-smoothing=no" -codec:a:0 ac3 -codec:a:1 ac3 -codec:a:2 ac3 -codec:a:3 ac3 -codec:a:4 ac3 -codec:s copy -r 120 C:\AVout\VTS_04_1(210820-042617.65).mkv`

The result:

1, Transcoding proceeded at about speed=1.0 with "Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 2048)".

2, While VSPIPE ran, it was FFMPEG (not VSPIPE) that dominated (by a factor of ~5x over VSPIPE) and "System Commit" rose, then leveled out at only 5.9GB.

3, All is well with playback.

---

Further Runs

I halved the bad thread_queue_size to 12441600, then halved it again to 6220800, et cetera, while monitoring "System Commit" in each run.
With each run, as I lowered thread_queue_size, I saw "System Commit" and CPU utilization beginning to balance out between VSPIPE and FFMPEG.

---

Outcome

At "-thread_queue_size 48600", I once again began getting "Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 48600)" and things settled down: FFMPEG & VSPIPE reversed dominance over CPU utilization (with FFMPEG now dominating) and "System Commit" rose linearly to 28.5GB and then leveled out.

It appears to me that "Thread message queue blocking" is a good thing -- a pipe that's not going to overflow if (or when) it runs for a long time. Is there a better way to assure this other than by twiddling thread_queue_size?

One other thing I don't understand: Why do I continue to get "Starting new cluster due to timestamp" notices -- I presume that's from the encoder -- when it's me that's writing the timestamps (via "settb=expr=1/120,setpts=expr=N")?

Notes:
All code and files are on a solid-state RAID0, Windows10, 4 dual cores (8 threads), 3.6 GHz, 32GB RAM + 100GiB pagefile.sys.
Tool used to monitor CPU utilization and "System Commit": Sysinternals, Process Explorer v16.21.

Answer (score 0):

From https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

```
-thread_queue_size size (input)
This option sets the maximum number of queued packets when reading from the file or device. With low latency / high rate live streams, packets may be discarded if they are not read in a timely manner; setting this value can force ffmpeg to use a separate input thread and read packets as soon as they arrive. By default ffmpeg only do this if multiple inputs are specified.
```

Another clue is

```
 While it ran, VSPIPE dominated the 8 threads (by a factor of ~2x over FFMPEG) and "System Commit" (sum of used RAM + used paging) maxed out at 126.3GB after rising steadily.
```

This is a buffering issue - ffmpeg is unable to process frames as fast as they are received. We can try 3 solutions.

a. Write to a different SSD/HDD as the input file SSD/HDD. This will exclude write speeds as a failure parameter.

b. Sine you are using windows - start your process as

```
start /b /high "cmd"
```

c. There is a big difference in speed between named pipes vs using anonymous pipes in Windows.

From - http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/986

```
windows standard input is very slow. So I switched to named pipes. It's up to 10x faster then standart input (pipe:).
```

Replace the anonymous pipes inputs `-`  and `-i pipe:`
by

```
-i \\.\pipe\pipename out.mkv
```

Windows has no official cmd utility - you can use this - github.com/psmay/windows-named-pipe-utils

Comment: Also `It appears to me that "Thread message queue blocking" is a good thing` - thats wrong. The thread message queue is only used by ffmpeg when it cannot keep up with the input frames.

Comment: Re: "thats wrong". It works. Without message queue blocking, vspipe overflows virtual memory.

Comment: Re: "There is a big difference in speed between named pipes vs using anonymous pipes in Windows" Have you used named pipes? How did you do it? I could only find 'C' code. I'm a user, not a codesmith. I have dumpped a list of all Windows named pipes. I'd include it here, but it's too big.

Comment: Regarding the rest of you suggestions -- I appreciate them! -- I am using a SSD RAID0 and I am boosting process priority. Good suggestions, though.

Comment: Perhaps there's a better way for FFmpeg to control the pipe. I've searched and can't find it.

Comment: There's a check box next to your post. I think that means it is an answer -- there's no pop up. It's not an answer.

Comment: @markfilipak The site is a way to help you improve your own attempts. Can you post what you tried with regard to named pipes ? See this post for a start - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584220/how-to-make-ffmpeg-write-its-output-to-a-named-pipe

Comment: I know next to nothing about named pipes. TCP/IP that is used as though a file? I think so. I assume that the server needs to open the named pipe, but I don't know how to create one. Regarding the subject of this thread, I've proceeded as I extensively described in this thread's original post. I asked for advice using '-thread_queue_size' effectively, especially in a script. I think the solution is a named pipe, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I tried your link. Apparently 'mkfifo' is the Linux method to create a named pipe. What's the Windows method?

Comment: Windows has no official cmd utility - you can use this - https://github.com/psmay/windows-named-pipe-utils

Comment: I can't use that. It's 'C' source code. I need something that will create a named pipe via cmd.exe. like 'mkdir' will make a new folder.

Comment: Look on the right side, there is a download link for a built-in utility.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have to figure out how to get the Python end to use it. I'll report back.